# Mapping entities in JPA/Hibernate without adding additional fields (just by using ids)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map those three entities to each other without adding any additional fields to any of them. They should only contain the fields that already exist. I'm also trying to only get columns in the tables that represent the currently existing entity fields- and no additional columns.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer orderId;
    private String title;
    private Customer customer;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Integer customerId;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private Integer commentId;
    private Integer orderId;
    private String details;
}
```

My understanding is that I can't simply use @OneToOne, @OneToMany and @ManyToOne mappings, because neither *Customer* nor *Comment* has a reference to *Order* . I'm trying to somehow reference the ids of *Customer* and *Comment* directly from *Order*.

I've tried using @MapsId and @JoinColumn but either I don't know how to properly use them, or they don't do what I think they do.

Is this task at all possible? If so, how to map them to each other?

Comment: That's not the idea of ORM! The goal of Hibernate is to map an object graph to database tables.

Comment: And my understanding is that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to create a uni-directional reference from Order to Customer and to Comment.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference to Comment you must use `@JoinColum`

The Customer reference assumes that there is a customer_id on the order table.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer orderId;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```